# keywords must be uset to create a variant record?

Tags: pascal, freepascal

what keywords must be used to create a variant record??

Comment: wich pascal compiler are you using?

Comment: This is how to do it: http://privat.rejbrand.se/howtoaccept.html

Answer (score 1):

@osabiri check the documentation for free pascal related to records.

```
Type  
  MyRec = Record  
          X : Longint;  
          Case byte of  
            2 : (Y : Longint;  
                 case byte of  
                 3 : (Z : Longint);  
                 );  
          end;
```

Important Note :

> The variant part must be last in the
>   record. The optional identifier in the
>   case statement serves to access the
>   tag field value, which otherwise would
>   be invisible to the programmer. It can
>   be used to see which variant is active
>   at a certain time1 . In effect, it
>   introduces a new field in the record.

check theses links

- [Free pascal Record types](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refsu15.html#x38-450003.3.2)
- [Free pascal Records](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Record)

Comment: could you please explain what do you mean by your last paragraph . Suppose i have a case as `case Integer of 0 : <somethiing> 1 : <something-2> end; How to decide which case will get executed ?

Answer (score 0):

`case`: Consider this standard example from http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devcommon/structuredtypes_xml.html

```
TEmployee = record
  FirstName, LastName: string[40];
  BirthDate: TDate;
  case Salaried: Boolean of
    True: (AnnualSalary: Currency);
    False: (HourlyWage: Currency);
end;
```